# Bootstrap best practices?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, web, bootstrap-4

I do both web design and development. I usually prefer to write my own CSS and not use any frameworks. On my current project the client said after I finished the design that it would help their dev team if I could also code the HTML & CSS. Their requirement was to use Bootstrap 4.

I said OK and got to work. However I have some questions about best practices when working with Bootstrap.
For example, say I want to have a **.navbar-text** that needs a left border with a certain non-theme color. My questions are:

- Should I create a new class for this, or just overwrite the **.navbar-text** class? Usually I follow BEM and would create a new class for this, but I'm not sure if that wouldn't be confusing in this instance.
- Since I'm already adding a CSS rule for the border, should I continue to add Bootstrap utility classes on the element, or should I just add CSS to my new rule? Say I want to add some left padding, should I add the **pl-2** class to the element, or should I add **padding-left: 0.5rem** to my CSS rule?

I want to make my code as easy as possible for their dev team to work with and I'm not sure how to proceed. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: usually i'm create new class, example btn btn-transparent-dark or edit the class, btn btn-primary, i change btn-primary color with same class name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should I create a new class for this, or just overwrite the
>   .navbar-text class? Usually I follow BEM and would create a new class
>   for this, but I'm not sure if that wouldn't be confusing in this
>   instance.

Create a new class. Overwriting or changing bootstrap classes is a no-go, because if they eventually upgrade to a new version of bootstrap, or start using a CDN vs locally hosted (or vice versa) stuff will stop working the way it used to and they won't know why. Leaving bootstrap as bootstrap makes it easy for a new developer to come along and not have to questions "is this bootstrap, or their specific flavor of bootstrap".

EDIT:

To clarify, in the case of your example I would make a utility class and add it to the element. So in the html you would have `class="navbar-text left-border"` and in my css `.navbar-text.left-border{border-left: 1px solid black;}` rather than `.navbar-text{border-left: 1px solid black !important;}`

> Since I'm already adding a CSS rule for the border, should I continue
>   to add Bootstrap utility classes on the element, or should I just add
>   CSS to my new rule? Say I want to add some left padding, should I add
>   the pl-2 class to the element, or should I add padding-left: 0.5rem to
>   my CSS rule?

Add it to your existing rule. Think about it this way:

Say you change your mind and don't actually want that padding anymore, or you want to change it to a new value. Would you rather change it in one place in your css, or everywhere you used that class in your html?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Regarding this: _Would you rather change it in one place in your css, or everywhere you used that class in your html?_ - Yes, that's my opinion as well, and that's the way I usually code, but I wasn't sure if it was the "bootstrap way". I mean if that's the case then why have all these utility classes for padding/margins etc in the first place?

Comment: They are meant to be used in cases where you have a single instance of a class that could use some padding, but you don't want to create a whole new class. The reason they include them in boostrap is so that they are all consistent and follow a pattern (`{property}{sides}-{size}`) rather than people creating their own super verbose utility classes (`.padding-left-5px`)